# Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn) doesn't connect to wireless networks

Tags: networking, wireless, 14.10, connection

I'm using 6-7 years old *LG MB500*, just installed Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn), and I can't connect to my school network (*WPA-WPA2 ENTERPRISE,TLS, MSCHAPv2, no CA certificate*).

The computer displays all the available networks, but when I try to connect to any, it just disconnects after trying for a few minutes.

I tried `system-ca-certs=false`, but it didn't work either. There are no other WiFi networks in my school, so I don't know if other types of Network work or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling and re-enabling your wireless.  Settings > Network > Wireless  and toggle switch it off and then back on. Or

```
ifconfig wlan0 down


ifconfig wlan0 up
```